# Paste from Word.doc leaves too much editing for user

Tags: wordpress, ms-word, converters, docx

I'm trying to find a way that works for the secretary of our association to paste or load minutes and other ms word documents to a wordpress post page without it requiring her to edit the pasted page with html tags or style="" entries.

I've tried useing the pre-formatted tag but it does not preserve her word.docx formatting. I've to tried three plugins that work to varying degrees to preserve word.docx formatting but always leave editing to be done.  I tried an "embed" plugin, but it leaves a frame around the page and doesn't appear to be responsive with respect to window sizes.  I tried writting my own code to load from a url a saved .html version of her files as a page within a page but that looks to be a bigger project than I'm ready to tackle.

I'm looking for coding solutions, plugin solutions, or even suggestions to ask this question on another venue.

Comment: Is she using Word's _Styles_ feature appropriately (i.e. using it to mark-up the document's structure) or is she just selecting text and clicking Bold/Underline/Italic? - or using line-breaks instead of paragraphs (or vice-versa)? I ask, because there's _a lot_ of people out there who think they know how to use MS Word, but are unaware of their own ignorance of Word's functionality (that said, can you ask her to use LaTeX or Markdown in future?)

Comment: Thanks, Dai.  Good question.  I haven't asked her.